# PHP SQL query returning with random characters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In my SQL database, the row "actor_id" has the value:

```
00f98c228af5491b83430c97621fe108
```

However, this returns (when var_dumped):

```
array(8) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "275"
  ["player_id"]=>
  string(16) "Fp�+5Bԥ��s0��"
  ["reason"]=>
  string(16) "distrurbing chat"
  ["expired"]=>
  string(10) "1425891575"
  ["actor_id"]=>
  string(16) "��"��I�C�b�"
  ["pastActor_id"]=>
  string(16) "�qGݯ�E��O8�'d�"
  ["pastCreated"]=>
  string(10) "1425890675"
  ["created"]=>
  string(10) "1425891613"
}
```

Notice how the columns have question marks, random characters?
How can I get it to return the proper value?

Here is my code:

```
                $conn = $api->getSQL('minecraft');
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM bm_player_mute_records_prison ORDER BY pastCreated DESC LIMIT 1";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                    var_dump($row);
                }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a Problem with encoding.

Comment: You might need to change the character set, e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html

Comment: @Dave I've tried using "mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");" & mysqli_set_charset($conn, "UTF8"); & header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: It looks like binary data, are you sure that the data in the database is what you think it is? Where are you pulling actor_id from to get 00f98c228af5491b83430c97621fe108? Is that base64 encoded, but perhaps when you're pulling it you're not base64 decoding it?

Comment: What's the column type? Is it a binary data type such as `VARBINARY`?

Comment: @Halfstop All I know is that it is a "UUID", unique identifier. I need that exact result in order to do anything with it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Its "binary(16)"

Comment: To get a better idea of what you're pulling out, you can try HEX(field) for any field to see the actual byte contents.

Comment: @Toby could you show the HTML document definition? and headers? it is not sql problem just visualisation i believe. And what type is your `actor_id` field?

Comment: Why are you storing integer values in `BINARY(16)` fields? You probably need `INT` or in cases of gigantic amounts of data, `BIGINT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its "binary(16)"

Well, that's what *binary* implies: it isn't text so it won't look nice.

- From the MySQL side, you have functions like [HEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) to get a printable representation.
- In PHP you have [bin2hex()](http://php.net/bin2hex).

Comment: So you're saying I should change:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bm_player_mute_records_prison ORDER BY pastCreated DESC LIMIT 1";

to

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bm_player_mute_records_prison ORDER BY HEX(pastCreated) DESC LIMIT 1";

?

Comment: I don't know what your exact needs are, but you *could* replace stuff like `SELECT player_id` with `SELECT HEX(player_id) AS player_id` (use an alias you don't get a funky column name). I'd probably format it from the PHP side. I'll edit my answer with that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using decrypt functions for the rows

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

I'll vote for it being MD5 encryption of something.  An MD5 is 128 bits, the length of that hex.  There *no* way to `un-MD5` to find what it came from.  (That is a *feature* of MD5.)

I'll vote that that it is *not* a UUID.  `SELECT UuidFromBin(unhex('00f98c228af5491b83430c97621fe108'));` --> `8af5491b-8c22-00f9-8343-0c97621fe108`, which is not a valid UUID, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier .  I got the conversion function from my blog on UUIDs:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid .